Xunit testing of code that use System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings does not load App.Config from project
We are migrating code from .Net Framework to .Net 7, and one of the requirements is continuing to get configuration from App.Config files. When I try to test a library that contains a reference to a System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings value, it has a null value, even though running the project normally the value exists.
I've created a minimal example project for the issue here.
The example code to be tested:
namespace ConfigService;

public class ConfigService
{
    public string GetValue()
    {
        string result = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["example"];
        return result;
    }

}

The app.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="example" value="exampleValue" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>

A class to run the project, which prints out the value from the app.config correctly:
using ConfigService;

Console.WriteLine(new ConfigService.ConfigService().GetValue());

And the test that fails because no app.config values are loaded when the dll is run by XUnit
namespace ConfigService.Tests;

public class ConfigService_Test
{
    [Fact]
    public void GetValue_Test()
    {
        var configService = new ConfigService();
        string result = configService.GetValue();

        Assert.Equal("exampleValue", result);
    }
}

Because of the shear amount of configuration the .Net Framework code has, it would be very helpful to find a workaround to this issue, without needing to convert all the config files to json and use the more modern configuration pattern.
